# Tutorial for CUDA + OpenGl

Tags: opengl, cuda

I'm looking for simple beginner's tutorial for CUDA with OpenGL, and how to set the CUDA environment on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For setting the CUDA dev tools:

http://lifeofaprogrammergeek.blogspot.com/2008/05/cuda-development-in-ubuntu.html

The official documentation for CUDA 3.1 is [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_1/toolkit/docs/NVIDIA_CUDA_C_ProgrammingGuide_3.1.pdf), is good to have it as a reference, and a easier tutorial is [this](http://llpanorama.wordpress.com/cuda-tutorial/).

Answer (score 3):

[Nvidia's site](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/sdk/website/samples.html)  has lots of samples specific to linux

Answer (score 0):

In the easier tutorial series that [Matias Valdenegro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/349130/matias-valdenegro) mentions, [part 15](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/cuda-supercomputing-for-the-masses-part/222600097) is the one that talks about CUDA and OpenGL.
Also [this](http://gpucomputing.net/?q=node/182) post gives links to some interesting tutorials.